# decoding the response from $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, .post

This is my javascript

```
<script>
    function checkEmail(email) {
        $.post('<?=base_url()?>checkemail',{ emailid : $('#inputEmailId').val() },function(d){
                CC = eval(d);
                alert(CC);
            });
    }
</script>
```

Part of PHP file contains

```
if ($parts) { //these details exist
        $obj->status = 'yes';
        }
    else {
        $obj->status = 'uni';
    }

    $res[] = $obj;
```

When I `print_r($res)` I get `status=>'yes'`

But when I `alert(CC)` in my javascript
I get

```
function array() {
[native code]
}
```

How do I alert the `status` in javascript?

Comment: why do you want to use array and object?? just use a variable and echo it.

Comment: The php code should return json_encode($res) and then remove the CC = eval(d) as d should be the valid result.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I tried your suggestion and passing only a variable. Even now it is not alerting the variable. In javascript console it says `yes is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked
PHP

```
if ($parts) { //these details exist
        $obj->status = 'yes';
        }
    else {
        $obj->status = 'uni';
    }

    $res[] = $obj;

    $data['content'] = json_encode($res);
```

Javascript

```
$.post('<?=base_url()?>checkemail',{ emailid : $('#inputEmailId').val() },function(d){
                CC = eval(d);
                alert(CC[0].status);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the `php` part should include a call to `json_encode`

```
if ($parts) { //these details exist
    $obj->status = 'yes';
}
else {
    $obj->status = 'uni';
}

// sending out $res should do it
// you can also add proper JSON headers if the content is not properly formatted
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode($obj);
```

Your javascript should look like this

```
function checkEmail(email) {
    $.post('<?=base_url()?>checkemail',{ emailid : $('#inputEmailId').val() },function(d){
            alert(d.status);
        });
}
```

Comment: after doing this errors went but alert was `undefined`

Comment: there was a mistake in my code that @Niranjan kindly edited out, I was sending out `$res` instead of `$obj`, please see again

Comment: This is the correct answer. If this does not work, something else is wrong and we need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

The php part can be changed like this.

Instead of using `object` and `array` use a `variable`. No need to complicate using objects and arrays for simple thing.

```
if ($parts) { //these details exist
    $status = 'yes';
    }
else {
    $status = 'uni';
}

echo $status;
```

Comment: did it, Even now it is not alerting the variable. In javascript console it says `yes is not defined`

Comment: can you add complete php code?? have you used a variable by name `yes`??

Comment: This is my complete php code
`$data['layout'] = 'layout_blank.tpl.php';
 $d['emailid'] = $_GET['emailid'];
 
 $parts = $participants->find($d);
 
 if ($parts) { //these details exist
  $res = 'yes';
  }
 else {
  $res = 'uni';
 }
 
 $data['content'] = $res;`